# Skipped tests due to incorrect data provider configuration

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I am working with testNG for the first time and had a question. I am trying to load some data from a json file and use the data in conjunction with dataProviders to write some tests. I have a helper file that has a parseData method which fetches data from a json file and builds maps of all the data I would need to test with. In my main test file, I define a test as follows:

In my main test file, I also have a BeforeClass method that loads calls the parseData method in the tDataHelper class.

Every time the test is run though, it gets skipped because the tDataHelper file has empty mappings everytime I try to debug the createStudents data provider. I think this has to do with static vs instance and I am not sure what is wrong exactly. Does the below code look like its ok and it should work? Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
    public class testStudents
    {
        private static tDataHelper helper = new tDataHelper();

        @BeforeClass
        public void setup() throws Exception
        {
            tDataHelper.parseData();
        }

        @FunctionalTest
        @Test(dataProvider = "createStudents", dataProviderClass = tDataHelper.class)
        public void testCreateStudents(List<Student> studentsToCreate){}
    }


    public class tDataHelper
    {
        private static List<Student> studentsToCreate = new HashSet<>();

        static void parseData() throws Exception
        {
            // read in json file and add students to the students list
            // studentsToCreate.add(node.parse(....))
        }

        @DataProvider
        public static Object[][] createStudents()
        {
            return new Object[][]{
                {
                    studentsToCreate
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide more details or specific example?

Comment: @amitbhoraniya Hi, I added in some more detail hoping it helps

Comment: Thanks...these may be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be there is configuration issues in your data provider class.

Do you want to iterate loop over all student ? Right! Then your test method should be like below.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "createStudents", dataProviderClass = tDataHelper.class)
public void testCreateStudents(Student studentsToCreate){}
```

I have updated sample with replacing Student class with String class, below is working example.
Please cross check with below code.

```
public class tDataHelper {
    private static List<String> studentsToCreate = new ArrayList<String>();

    static void parseData() throws Exception {
        studentsToCreate.add("user1");
        studentsToCreate.add("user2");
        studentsToCreate.add("user3");
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] createStudents() {
        Object[][] objArray = new Object[studentsToCreate.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < studentsToCreate.size(); i++) {
            objArray[i] = new Object[1];
            objArray[i][0] = studentsToCreate.get(i);
        }
        return objArray;
    }
}

public class testStudents {
    private static tDataHelper helper = new tDataHelper();

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        tDataHelper.parseData();
    }
    @Test(dataProvider = "createStudents", dataProviderClass = tDataHelper.class)
    public void testCreateStudents(String studentsToCreate) {
        System.out.println(studentsToCreate);
    }
}
```

I am using [qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) for [Json Data Provider](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#json-data-provider), so manually you don't need to parse your json data and get rid from data provider class.

Answer (score 0):

A data provider is supposed to be standalone and not initialized from the outside. Check [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders).

You have options:

1. Using a data provider how it is designed for:

   ```
   public class testStudents {

       @FunctionalTest
       @Test(dataProvider = "createStudents", dataProviderClass = tDataHelper.class)
       public void testCreateStudents(List<Student> studentsToCreate){}
   }


   public class tDataHelper {

       private static List<Student> parseData() throws Exception {
           // read in json file and add students to the students list
           // studentsToCreate.add(node.parse(....))
       }

       @DataProvider
       public static Object[][] createStudents() {
           return new Object[][]{
               {
                   parseData();
               }
           };
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using your class a utils one and use it in your test:

   ```
   public class testStudents {

       private static List<Student> studentsToCreate;

       @BeforeClass
       public void setup() throws Exception {
           studentsToCreate = tDataHelper.parseData();
       }

       @FunctionalTest
       @Test
       public void testCreateStudents() {}
   }


   public class tDataHelper {

       public static List<Student> parseData() throws Exception {
           // read in json file and add students to the students list
           // studentsToCreate.add(node.parse(....))
       }    
   }
   ```